# In which cases it makes sense to use factory classes instead of static functions?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Currently I have created a ABCFactory class that has a single method creating ABC objects. Now that I think of it, maybe instead of having a factory, I could just make a static method in my ABC Method. What are the pro's and con's on making this change? Will it not lead to the same? I don't foresee having other classes inherit ABC, but one never knows!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality, if you want to get the benefits of a factory class, you need the static method in it's own class.  This will allow you to later create new factory classes, or reconfigure the existing one to get different behaviors.  For example, one factory class might create Unicorns which implement the IFourHoovedAnimal interface.  You might have an algorithm written that does things with IFourHoovedAnimal's and needs to instantiate them.  Later you can create a new factory class that instead instantiates Pegasus's which also implement IFourHoovedAnimal's.  The old algorithm can now be reused for Pegasus's just by using the new factory!  To make this work both the PegasusFactory and the UnicornFactory must inherit from some common base class(usually an abstract class).

So you see by placing the static method in it's own factory class, you can swap out factory classes with newer ones to reuse old algorithms.  This also works for improving testability, because now unit tests can be fed a factory that creates mock objects.

I have done the latter before (static factory method on the class that you are creating instances of) for very small projects, but it was only because I needed it to help refactor some old code, but keep changes to a minimum.  Basically in that case I had factored out a chunk of code that created a bunch of ASP.NET controls, and stuff all those controls into a user control.  I wanted to make my new user control property based, but it was easier for the old legacy code to create the user control with a parameter based constructor.

So I created a static factory method that took all the parameters, and then instanced the user control and set it's properties based on the parameters.  The old legacy code used this static method to create the user control, and future code would use the "prettier" properties instead.

Answer (score 4):

Having a single, static method makes this much more difficult to test whereas having an instantiable object allows this to be easier to test. Also, dependency injection is later more of an option with the non-static solution.

Of course, if you don't need any of this, then these are not good arguments.

Comment: Why is it easier to test with a non-static method?

Comment: @devoured elysium: for instance, a test class might include a subclass of the original which overrode the method, for instrumentation or short-circuiting normal behavior.  That's not (easily) possible with a static method.

Comment: @devoured elysium - Because you can't pass a static class as a parameter to the test methods (at least not well). This is related to the second point about dependency injection. But, as Jaxidian said, these points may not be important.

Answer (score 3):

The main advantage of the factory method is the ability to hide reference to a specific class behind an interface. Since static methods can not be a part of the interface, static factory methods are basically the same as the constructor method itself. The only useful application of the static factory methods is to provide access to a private constructor - what is  commonly used for singleton-pattern implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For concrete classes, factory methods are really just a method of indirection around creating the actual type (which isn't to say they aren't useful, but as you've found, the factory method could really be *anywhere*).

Where the factory method really shines though is when your method creates instances of an interface type.

Answer (score 1):

The "D" in [Uncle Bob's SOLID Principles of Object Oriented Design](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) is "The Dependency Inversion Priciple" *Depend on abstractions, not on concretions.*

An extreme following of that principle could have your main class create all your factories, with each factory using other factories via interfaces. The only appearance of "new" (creating concrete objects) would be in your main class, and your factories. All your objects would work with interfaces (abstractions), with the concrete dependencies obtained from supplied factory implementations.

You could then very easily adjust, or provide multiple Main classes customised for different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Overuse of design patterns are dangerous, and creational design patterns make sense when you have class hierarchies with defined interfaces, or need to build rather complex objects. If you have a simple design, use simple solutions. Therefore, in your case, Factory Method would be enough

Yes, you are right, it is another design pattern  :)